# Why do i get the avrage of the subcategory and not the avrage of category per year?

Tags: powerbi

[image]

When i drag in a tabel
and just have

- -YEAR
- -Kategory
- -Summa

I will get the medium value  of 895,50  (815 + 976 / 2) for february

I don't want it to separeate the Subcategory

I want it to show
1791
when i just mark february

and if i use February and March
It sould say

2022 Inköp 2435,5
Becouse that the Medium of February and Marsh on the category

Comment: This looks like a calculated column, which means that the row context limits the calculation to single row, which in your case seems to be subcategory.

Comment: @Stachu from his text he appears to be using the `Summa` column as an implicit measure, but he apparently wants to do calculations that are more advanced than the ones supported by implicit measures.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what you are asking (likely the reason for your downvotes). I think you are after a monthly average measure. Since your sample data is extremely limited I assume that each month will have exactly one date. Ideally this type of calculation should be handled by using a calendar table as a basis for month values, but for your sample data, try this:

```
Monthly average = 
AVERAGEX ( 
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Datum] ) , 
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Summa] ) )
)
```